# If $\mu_1\le\mu_2$ on an algebra, then $\mu_1\le\mu_2$ on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We suppose that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are finite measures on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ generated by the algebra $\Sigma_0$.

My question is how to prove that if $\mu_1(A) \leq \mu_2(A)$ holds for all $A$ in $\Sigma_0$, then it holds for all $A$ in $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [an approximation argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra): if $A\in \Sigma$ and $\varepsilon>0$, take $A'\in\Sigma_0$ such that $(\mu_1+\mu_2)(A\Delta A')\lt\varepsilon$.

Then 
$$\mu_1(A)=\mu_1(A')+(\mu_1(A)-\mu_1(A'))\leqslant \mu_2(A')+(\mu_1(A)-\mu_1(A'))\lt \mu_2(A')+\varepsilon\\
\leqslant \mu_2(A)+2\varepsilon.$$
We conclude, as $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary.

Comment: yes I see, thanks @davide