# Showing independence of rectangular events...

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose I have a sequence of independent random variables $\{X_n, n \in \mathbb N\}$.

How do I show formally that

$P((X_1,...,X_n)\in A, (X_{n+1},...)\in B) = P((X_1,...,X_n)\in A)P((X_{n+1},...)\in B)$

if $A$ is a rectangle in $\mathcal B^n$ and $B$ is a rectangle in $\mathcal B^{\infty}$?

I tried, but I'm stuck on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to deduce from the equality 
$$\tag{$\star$}P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\{X_i\in B_i\}\cap\bigcap_{j\in J}\{X_j\in B_j\} \right)=P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\{X_i\in B_i\}\right)\cdot P\left(\bigcap_{j\in J}\{X_j\in B_j\}\right)$$
for $I$ and $J$ finite disjoint subsets of $\mathbf N$ and $B_k$ Borel subsets  that 
$$\tag{1}P((X_1,...,X_n)\in A, (X_{n+1},...)\in B) = P((X_1,...,X_n)\in A)P((X_{n+1},...)\in B).$$
Using $(\star)$, we obtain that $(1)$ holds if $A$ is a finite disjoint union of products of Borel sets and $B$ a finite union of set of the form $\prod_{j=1}^NB_j\times \mathbb R\times\dots $.
Sets of this form generate respectively the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbf R^n$ and $\mathbf R^\infty$ and are algebras. We can thus conclude by [an approximation argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand well your answer. In particular why $A$ have to be a finite disjoint union of products of Borel sets? A product of borel sets isn't enough? Then what do you mean by $\prod_{j=1}^NB_j\times \mathbb R\times\dots $? Cartesian product of cartesian products? My mind is exploding!

Comment: The set $A$ is not necessarily of the form $A_1\times \dots\times A_n$, for example if $A:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n), x_1\dots x_n\geqslant 0\}$: that's why we consider the unions. The notation $\prod_{j=1}^NB_j\times \mathbb R\times\dots$ means the subset of $\mathcal B^\infty$ such that the $N$ first factors are the $B_j$ and the others the whole real line.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I should meditate a while on this :-)