# How to show that the probability that $\mathbb{Z}^d$ is internally spanned is equal to 1? (bootstrap percolation)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, cellular-automata, percolation

**Presentation of the model:** we consider the regular lattice created from $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

- At $t=0$, each site is said "active" independently with a probability $p$, "inactive" otherwise.
- At $t$, if a site is inactive, it becomes active if at least $k$ of its neighbours are active.

We call neighbour of $x$ each element of $V(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}^d, ||x-y||=1\}$.
We note $S_t$ the set of the active sites.

**My question:** When : $p>0$ and $k\leq d$, how to show that the probability that $S_\infty=\mathbb{Z}^2$ is 1?

**Clues:** someone has told me, without further explanation, that this event is invariant by translation. Thus, by ergodicity of the model, the probability is equal to 0 or 1. But I don't know what does "ergodicity" means, and I don't know how to show that it's invariant and ergodic...

Comment: The state of different sites at time $0$ are assumed independent, I presume?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I forgot to precise it! Just edited it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is originally due to [A. van Enter](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01019705).  Suppose that $k\leq d$ and $p>0$.  For simplicity, let us consider the case $d=2$.  The general case is similar but more elaborate (I presume).

First, observe that an active rectangular region with a protuberance along one of its sides is extended in a number of steps into a larger active rectangular region:

[image: rectangle with a protuberance]
$\qquad\longrightarrow\qquad$
[image: larger rectangle]

It follows that an active $n\times n$ square grows to an active $(n+2)\times(n+2)$ square provided there are four active sites on its boundary one along each of its sides.

[image: droplet]
$\qquad\longrightarrow\qquad$
[image: grown droplet]

Let us call a square region *properly fenced* if there are four active sites on its boundary one along each of its sides.  So, we know that if an active $n\times n$ square is properly fenced, it will grow into an active $(n+2)\times(n+2)$ square.  If the new square is also properly fenced, the active square will grow even larger, and so on.  In particular, if a square is active and properly fenced and all (centered) squares surrounding it are also properly fenced, then every site on the lattice will eventually be active.

[image]

Let us call a $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$ square centered at a site $(i,j)$ *critical* if for every $m\geq n$, the $(2m+1)\times(2m+1)$ square centered at $(i,j)$ is properly fenced.  In conclusion

> ($\star$)$\quad$ If there is a critical active square somewhere on the lattice, then
>   every site on the lattice will eventually be active.

In order to prove the claim, it is sufficient to show that with probability $1$, somewhere on the lattice there is a critical active square.

Let us first show that

> ($\star\star$)$\quad$ There is an $N$ sufficiently large such that with *positive*
>   probability, the $(2N+1)\times(2N+1)$ square centered at the origin is active
>   and critical.

*Argument*.
This is essentially a Borel-Cantelli argument.
Let $B_n$ denote the $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$ square centered at the origin.  Note that the probability that at the beginning $B_n$ is not properly fenced is no larger than $4(1-p)^n$.  Therefore, for each $N$,
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ not critical}) &=
      \mathbb{P}(\text{$B_n$ not properly fenced for some $n\geq N$}) \\
   &\leq
      \sum_{n\geq N} \mathbb{P}(\text{$B_n$ not properly fenced}) \\
   &\leq
      \sum_{n\geq N} 4(1-p)^n \;.
\end{align*}
Since $p>0$, the sum on the right-hand side converges, and moreover it is smaller than $1$ for sufficiently large $N$.
Therefore, if we choose $N$ sufficiently large, $\mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ critical})>0$.  Since the event that $B_N$ is critical and the event that $B_N$ is active are independent, we obtain
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ active and critical}) &=
      \mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ active})\times\mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ critical}) \\
   &=
      p^{(2N+1)^2}\mathbb{P}(\text{$B_N$ critical}) \\
   &> 0
\end{align*}
for sufficiently large $N$.
$\square$

It follows from ($\star$) and ($\star\star$) that

> ($\clubsuit$)$\quad$ $\mathbb{P}(\text{every site will eventually be active})>0$.

Here is where the concept of ergodicity comes in.

Let $E\subseteq\{\square,\blacksquare\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ denote the set of all configurations starting from which the bootstrap cellular automaton turns every site eventually active.  As you mentioned, this event is invariant under translations: if we translate a configuration in $E$ we get another configuration in $E$ and if we translate a configuration outside $E$ we get another configuration outside $E$.  This is because the bootstrap cellular automaton treats all sites in the same fashion.

In your model, the starting configuration is chosen using independent biased coin flips ($\blacksquare$ with probability $p$ and $\square$ with probability $1-p$).
The probability law of independent coin flips has the property that every translation-invariant event has probability either $0$ or $1$ [proof via basic measure theory].  This property is one of the definitions of what it means for a probability law to be *ergodic for translations*.  As a corollary, $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is either $0$ or $1$.  Since we already know from ($\clubsuit$) that $\mathbb{P}(E)>0$, we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(E)=1$.

Q.E.D.

---

Let me give you an alternative intuition why the concept of ergodicity came in.  Clearly, the origin has no special role in ($\star\star$): if the $(2N+1)\times(2N+1)$ square centered at the origin is active and critical with probability $\varepsilon>0$, then for every site $(i,j)$, the probability that the $(2N+1)\times(2N+1)$ square centered at $(i,j)$ is active and critical is also $\varepsilon$.  (This is again because the bootstrap cellular automaton does not distinguish between different frames of reference.)

Having the strong law of large numbers in mind, we may expect that

> ($\spadesuit$)$\quad$ Almost surely, the density of sites $(i,j)$ for which the
>   $(2N+1)\times(2N+1)$ square centered at the $(i,j)$ is active and
>   critical is $\varepsilon$.

This would have followed from the law of large numbers if the events for different sites were independent, but obviously these events are not independent.  The ergodic theorem (a far-reaching generalization of the law of large numbers) and the ergodicity of the distribution of independent coin flips mentioned above imply that ($\spadesuit$) is indeed true.  It follows that almost surely there is at least one (in fact infinitely many) critical active squares on the lattice.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is perfect

Comment: "The probability law of independent coin flips has the property that every translation-invariant event has probability either 0 or 1 [proof via basic measure theory]" :

I wonder whether you could help me to show this. I'm studying the bootstrap percolation for a school project, but this result is hard to show for me because we don't have any lesson about measure theory.

Comment: If you know the proof of [Kolmogorov's zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_zero%E2%80%93one_law), this is kind of similar.  Namely, it is enough to show that every translation-invariant event is independent of itself!  Just check that if $E$ is independent of itself, its probability has to be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: In order to show the independence, we approximate $E$ with a local event, that is, an event that depends on the color of only finitely many positions.  Check that if $A$ is a local event, $k\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $B$ is the event that the translation of the outcome configuration by $k$ is in $A$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent as long as $k$ is large.

Comment: The argument that every event can be approximated by local events follows from basic measure theory, see e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra).   Increasing the accuracy of the approximation, you can argue that $E$ can't help but being independent of itself.