# Citation for a theorem about filtrations

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, martingales

My Professor stated the following statement: Let $(\Sigma,\nu,\mathcal{F})$ be a measure space, $\mathcal{F}$ a sigma-algebra. Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be a filtration, and let $A$ be a measurable set. Then $\forall\varepsilon>0 \exists n$ and a set $A_n$ such that $A_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$ and $\nu(A\triangle A_n)<\varepsilon$.

I'm looking for a source for this claim (or a generalization) of it, mainly to be able to state it properly and write a citation, but if there's a source with proof (for personal interest mainly) that will be great!

I appreciate any help :)

**Edit:** In the comments I was referred to a great post here [Approximating a σ-algebra by a generating algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra)
. In it I'm mostly interested in  a comment made by the user shalop, on the use of the martingale convergence theorem. Although it says it can be done "easily enough", I didn't succeed. For easy access, the theorem discussed in the post is

> Theorem. Let (X,B,μ) a finite measure space, where μ is a positive
> measure. Let A⊂B an algebra generating B.
>
> Then for all B∈B and ε>0, we can find A∈A such that
> μ(AΔB)=μ(A∪B)−μ(A∩B)<ε.

and the answer is:

> Let F=σ(Ei:i∈N) be countably generated. For each n let Fn:=σ(Ei:i≤n)
> so that Fn form a filtration. Now take a set A∈F and consider the
> martingale Xn:=E[1A|Fn]. This converges a.s. to 1A, from which one may
> conclude easily enough (just to clarify, this would only prove that F
> can be approximated arbitrary closely by elements of the algebra which
> is generated by the Ei)...

[I would have asked there myself but can't comment]

Comment: I don't think this is even true in general. In a [filtration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(probability_theory)) the sigma algebras ${\cal F}_n$ do not need to increase to ${\cal F}\,.$ Even ${\cal F}_n=\{\emptyset,\Sigma\}\forall n$ is a filtration. If $\nu(A)$ is anything other than zero or one there is no way that we can find those $A_n\,.$

Comment: Thank you for responding! What if the filtration does increase?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra) has the answer to your question. According to the book by Rick Durret it boils down to ${\cal F}$ being generated by all ${\cal F}_n\,.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximating a $\sigma$-algebra by a generating algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra)

Comment: @KurtG. I think it just might! starting to read this more in detail now. Thank you so much!