# Approximate set in a generating algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space and let $\mathcal{A}^0$ be an algebra generating $\mathcal{A}$. For each $\epsilon>0$ and $A\in \mathcal{A}$, [one can find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra) $A^0\in\mathcal{A}^0$ such that $\mu(A\Delta A^0)<\epsilon$, where $\mu$ is a finite measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$. Now, if we're given another finite measure $\nu$  on $(X,\mathcal{A})$, can one find $A^0\in\mathcal{A}^0$ such that both $\mu(A\Delta A^0)<\epsilon_1$ and $\nu(A\Delta A^0)<\epsilon_2$ for some $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$? (*A similar argument is used in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/sufficient-condition-for-absolute-continuity-of-measures)*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming the measures are non-negative:**

Consider the non-negative measure $\eta$ given by $\eta = \mu + \nu$. Do you see how you can proceed from here?

In full detail, given $A\in \mathcal{A}$ we can find $A^{0} \in \mathcal{A}^{0}$ such that *this new measure* is small on $A\Delta A^{0}$: for $\varepsilon = \min\{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2\}$ we have that:
$$\varepsilon > \eta(A\Delta A^{0}) =\mu(A\Delta A^{0}) + \nu(A\Delta A^{0}).$$
Now, as both measures are non-negative the previous inequality implies what you wanted to prove.